# регулярные выражения получение массива значений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Дан текст в который включены ключи raz: dva: tri:
текст может располагаться как перед ключами так и после

На выходе нужно получить массив,
где ключ это raz , dva , tri,
а ДАННЫЕ - текст располагающийся после ключа до следующего ключа или до конца текста, если не встретился ключ.
Очередность ключей может быть – произвольная.
 Если в тексте ключ встречается второй раз - в массиве он должен быть переписан.
В решении должны использоваться регулярки.

Мое решение

(raz:|dva:|tri:)(.*?)

выбирает только ключи , тоесть каким образом доработать чтобы выбирало и значения

Comment: Какой именно движок используете? В разных языках разные нюансы.

Comment: `(?s)(raz:|dva:|tri:)(.*?)(?=raz:|dva:|tri:|\z)`. Где `?s` - точка захватывает символы переноса строки и возврата каретки, `\z` - конец строки (файла).

Comment: php, но проверяю на regex101.com

Comment: удивительно, ваше выражение работает ... осталось только разобраться как

Comment: Если оно работает, то вы используете его не в 
Python и не в JS.